# Jmeter Threads not executing independently

Tags: jmeter, jsr223, jmeter-4.0

I am using jmeter 4.0 to simulate android app.
the app generate data upload to server.

jmeter script is like.

```
Thread Group -> 13500 threads rampup : 20min
|->once only controller
|->Simple controller
  |->HTTP Request(get number of uploads)
  |->JSR223 Sampler (parse response,set up loop var)
  |->Loop Controller
       |->JSR223 Sampler (generate data)
       |->HTTP Request (send data)
       |->Take Action Sampler
          |->Constant Timer
```

When script is executed. At first it execute all the once only controller of all the threads then HTTP request for all the threads. So on.
Jmeter is executing each sampler for all the threads then procedding to the sampler.Threads execution is not independent.
I am printing the logs to the console from JSR223 Sampler.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to community. Thanks

Comment: It looks like not able to process so many threads concurrently. Even though cpu usage is not 100%. works fine with reduced thread count

Comment: how many threads do you have ?

Comment: I am running 6000 threads. I figured that threads are slow at JSR223 Sampler (this is where I am generating .zip file to be uploaded to the server)

Comment: Thanks for feedback. So I guess you can accept my answer right ?

Answer (score 0):

No that’s not what is happening.
You think it is most probably because you start all threads at same time.

In Jmeter all threads run independently.

Add a slight delay using rampup field so that threads gradually start and you’ll see.

Comment: I am starting threads at rampup of 20min. However when I run script. Looking at my server logs it look like all sampler are not executing independently. Suppose if server has sent response for Sampler A of thread 1. Server is not receiving any request for Sampler B until all Sampler A from 13500 threads has finished